# setURLBlacklist not working as expected

Tags: detox

**Env:**
Detox 6.0.4
Node:8.9.4

I'm having hanging test, when adding `--debug-synchronization 5000` I see those messages all the time:

`detox info Sync App State: Waiting for network requests to finish.: (
detox info Sync     "http://localhost:1234/configurations/_?examplerequset
detox info Sync )
detox info Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread`

Then I've added this line to my test initiation

`await device.setURLBlacklist(['.*localhost:1234.*']);`

And I can see the corresponding log when the test starts:

`detox verb ws send: {"type":"invoke","params":{"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYConfiguration"},"method":"sharedInstance","args":[]}},"method":"setValue:forConfigKey:","args":[[".*localhost:1234.*"],"GREYConfigKeyURLBlacklistRegex"]},"messageId":1}
detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"invokeResult","messageId":1,"params":{"result":"(null)"}}`

But I'm still getting the same `Waiting for network requests to finish` log on the same URL. looks like it ignore my blacklist.

Help will be appreciated.